# Drawing multiple images on one canvas

Tags: javascript, image, html

I have an array that contains all the information about how the `image` should be drawn.  I want to draw 2 `images` and when I do it, it's only drawing the last image.  What can I do?

```
for(i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
{
    var sourceX = tiles[i][5];
    var sourceY = tiles[i][6];
    var sourceWidth = tiles[i][9];
    var sourceHeight = tiles[i][10];
    var destWidth = sourceWidth;
    var destHeight = sourceHeight;
    var destX = tiles[i][7];
    var destY = tiles[i][8];

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function()
    {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
    };
    imageObj.src = tiles[i][4];
}
```

Answer (score 20):

I couldn't explain more specific reasons, but here is the solution I figured out. It works for me.

```js
const getContext = () => document.getElementById('my-canvas').getContext('2d');

// It's better to use async image loading.
const loadImage = url => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => resolve(img);
    img.onerror = () => reject(new Error(`load ${url} fail`));
    img.src = url;
  });
};

// Here, I created a function to draw image.
const depict = options => {
  const ctx = getContext();
  // And this is the key to this solution
  // Always remember to make a copy of original object, then it just works :)
  const myOptions = Object.assign({}, options);
  return loadImage(myOptions.uri).then(img => {
    ctx.drawImage(img, myOptions.x, myOptions.y, myOptions.sw, myOptions.sh);
  });
};

const imgs = [
  { uri: 'http://placehold.it/50x50/f00/000?text=R', x: 15, y:  15, sw: 50, sh: 50 },
  { uri: 'http://placehold.it/50x50/ff0/000?text=Y', x: 15, y:  80, sw: 50, sh: 50 },
  { uri: 'http://placehold.it/50x50/0f0/000?text=G', x: 15, y: 145, sw: 50, sh: 50 }
];

imgs.forEach(depict);
```

```css
#my-canvas { background: #7F7F7F; }
```

```html
<canvas id="my-canvas" width="80" height="210"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not positive, but that imageObj may not be the imageObj you'd expect in the imageObj.onload function. Instead of doing

```
 context.drawImage(imageObj, sourceX, sourceY,
```

See what happens when you do

```
 context.drawImage(this, sourceX, sourceY,
```

Comment: this is likely a good part of the answer, and will probably be a solution. declaring local variables in a for-loop is the other issue I see here..

Comment: that is, the values being used with the method `context.drawImage` are still out of scope.. i.e. `sourceX` `sourceY`... will all likely be tiles[tiles.length -1] equivalent on every `imageObj` (or `this`) instance, right?

Answer (score 4):

If you're loading multiple images, it's recommended that you pre-load all of the images first.  See here for more information:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-loader/

Answer (score 1):

i had similar problems,
i like the solution from

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations

just call window.requestAnimationFrame(draw); from your draw function, it will run an infinit loop and draw your images as soon as they are ready

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution, and a recommended alternative; both use `<function>.bind(<this>[,<arg1>][,<arg2>])`

`bind` wraps the intended function, and performs a call on it using additional specified parameters (args). The first parameter of `bind` will be the `this` instance of the function. Setting it to `undefined` will pass the original `this` instance.

### anonymous function.

```js
  var settings;

  for(i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
  {
      settings = {};
      settings.sourceX = tiles[i][5];
      settings.sourceY = tiles[i][6];
      settings.sourceWidth = tiles[i][9];
      settings.sourceHeight = tiles[i][10];
      settings.destWidth = sourceWidth;
      settings.destHeight = sourceHeight;
      settings.destX = tiles[i][7];
      settings.destY = tiles[i][8];

      settings.imageObj = new Image();
      settings.imageObj.onload = function(args)
      {
         context.drawImage(args.image, args.sourceX, args.sourceY, args.sourceWidth, args.sourceHeight, args.destX, args.destY, args.destWidth, args.destHeight);
      }.bind(undefined, settings);
      settings.imageObj.src = tiles[i][4];
  }
```

---

I prefer **not to use** *anonymous functions* for common event handling though; instead, I would declare an object to store handlers.

That way you can replace the handler at runtime. In a manner like the following.

### declare object to store event handling functions

```js
  var Handlers = { 
      "drawImageHandler" : function drawImageHandler(args)
      {
          context.drawImage(args.image, args.sourceX, args.sourceY, args.sourceWidth, args.sourceHeight, args.destX, args.destY, args.destWidth, args.destHeight);
      }
  };

  function DebugInit() 
  {
      var func = Handlers.drawImageHandler;
      Handlers.drawImageHandler = function(func, args) {
         console.log("%o", args);
         func(args);
      }.bind(undefined, func);
  }


  var settings = {};
  DebugInit(); // when called, encapsulates Handlers.drawImageHandler;

  for(i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
  {
      settings = {};
      settings.sourceX = tiles[i][5];
      settings.sourceY = tiles[i][6];
      settings.sourceWidth = tiles[i][9];
      settings.sourceHeight = tiles[i][10];
      settings.destWidth = sourceWidth;
      settings.destHeight = sourceHeight;
      settings.destX = tiles[i][7];
      settings.destY = tiles[i][8];
      settings.imageObj = new Image();
      settings.imageObj.onload = Handlers.drawImageHandler.bind(undefined, settings);      
      settings.imageObj.src = tiles[i][4];
  }
```

***jsFiddle***: [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dugarjnd/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
img[0]=new Image();
img[0].src="imgimg/img"+i+".png";
img[0].onload=function(){
  cntxt.drawImage(this,400,i*100,100,100);
  i++;
  img[i]=new Image(); 
  img[i].src="invimg/img"+i+".png";
  img[i].onload=this.onload;
};
```

piece of my js game, i hope it helps cheers!

Comment: This creates an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  const createCanvas = async (imageSrc) => {
      img.src = imageSrc;
      await img.decode();
      context.drawImage(img, x, y, sw, sh)    
  }
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31510142)