# Problem with "drawImage()" in reportlab in python

Tags: python, image, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab

I'm trying to get a number of images into a PDF using reportlab. I've created a list with the file-names and need the program to go through the list adding the images in the coordinates (x=80, y=100; x=80, y=500; x=330, y=100; x=330, y=500). The problem I've encountered is that when I write the code to add the images the output PDF is blank (shows no page what so ever), it seems like it's overwriting the canvas.Canvas(".pdf") function.

Here's part of the scrypt:

for n in range(len(imagenes)): # "imagenes" is the list with the file names

```
  imagen = imagenes[n]
  
  pdf.drawImage(f"{imagen}", x=80, y=100)
  
  n += 1
 
  pdf.drawImage(f"{imagen}", x=80, y=500)
  
  n += 1
  
  pdf.drawImage(f"{imagen}", x=330, y=100)
  
  n += 1
  
  pdf.drawImage(f"{imagen}", x=330, y=500)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, If you're loading multiple images, it's recommended that you pre-load all of the images first. See here for more information:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-loader/

Also, maybe this answer can help you:

[Drawing multiple images on one canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404937/drawing-multiple-images-on-one-canvas)